# Webview in a scrollview to scroll entire view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have a webview. I want to keep the webview in a scroll view such that it looks like entire view is scrolling. Any suggestions will be greatly welcomed...

Comment: You want to scroll the webview itself or scroll the content inside the webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by extending the height of the web view, applying [clearColor] to the web view and adding drop shadows to it...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable the UserInteraction  of WebView.Hope it works.